# Binding a Canvas to a Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, graphics

I have a class called "WaferMap" that draws rectangles its own canvas. There is also a canvas in the main view as well.  I want to be able to bind the content of the canvas in the WaferMap class to the canvas on the GUI. What is the best way to do this?

The way I am doing it now is creating a canvas in the WaferMap class and then binding it to the canvas on the GUI using the ContentPresenter property of the canvas.

**WaferMap class:**

```
public class WaferMap : ViewModelBase
{
#region Fields

    protected const int rows = 23;
    protected const int cols = 23;
    protected int currentRow;
    protected int currentCol;
    protected DiePrint diePrint;
    protected List<BlueTape> blueTapeList;
    protected Canvas canvasToMap;

#endregion

#region Constructor

    public WaferMap(List<BlueTape> btList)
    {
        blueTapeList = new List<BlueTape>();
        blueTapeList = btList;
    }

#endregion

#region Properties

    public Canvas WaferMapCanvas
    {
        get
        {
            return canvasToMap;
        }
    }
    public List<BlueTape> BlueTapeList
    {
        get
        {
            return blueTapeList;
        }
    }

#endregion

#region Methods

    public void DrawWaferMap()
    {
        if (blueTapeList.Count > 0)
        {
            canvasToMap = new Canvas();
            foreach (BlueTape bt in blueTapeList)
            {
                if (bt.DiePrintList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DiePrint print in bt.DiePrintList)
                    {
                        // Create a new DiePrintRectangle and get its
                        // row and column coordinates
                        DiePrintRectangle diePrintRect = new DiePrintRectangle(print);

                        // Add the print to the canvas
                        canvasToMap.Children.Add(diePrintRect);

                        // Set the properties
                        Thickness margin = new Thickness(0);
                        diePrintRect.Margin = margin;
                        diePrintRect.Height = 25;
                        diePrintRect.Width = diePrintRect.Height;
                        diePrintRect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        diePrintRect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                        currentCol = Convert.ToInt32(print.Col * diePrintRect.Height);
                        currentRow = Convert.ToInt32(print.Row * diePrintRect.Height);
                        print.MapCol = currentCol;
                        print.MapRow = currentRow;
                        Canvas.SetLeft(diePrintRect, currentCol);
                        Canvas.SetTop(diePrintRect, currentRow);

                        // Get the color of the print fill and stroke
                        //diePrintRect.Stroke = GetDiePrintColor(bt);
                        diePrintRect.StrokeThickness = 12;
                        diePrintRect.Stroke = GetDiePrintColor(bt);
                        diePrintRect.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        diePrintRect.MouseDown += diePrintRect_MouseDown;
                        diePrintRect.MouseEnter += diePrintRect_MouseEnter;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my XAML:

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Canvas Name="mapCanvas">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding WaferMap}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```

**And in the code behind:**

*NOTE*: I have this setup for debugging the binding.  When the button "btnDoStuff" gets clicked, it will set the datacontext of the canvas on the GUI.

```
public partial class WaferTrackerWindow : Window
{
    WaferTrackerWindowViewModel wtw;
    public WaferTrackerWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SelectWaferButtonViewModel swbv = new SelectWaferButtonViewModel();
        wtw = new WaferTrackerWindowViewModel(tvwWaferList, txtFilter);            

        wtw.SelectWaferButtonViewModel = swbv;

        tvwDockPanel.DataContext = wtw.SelectWaferButtonViewModel;
        DataContext = wtw;
        btnChooseWafer.DataContext = wtw;
        btnSelectWafer.DataContext = wtw;
        btnExit.DataContext = wtw;
        tbkWafer.DataContext = wtw;

        btnDoStuff.Click += btnDoStuff_Click;
    }

    private void btnDoStuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mapCanvas.DataContext = wtw.WaferMap.WaferMapCanvas;
    }
```

For some reason, this is not working.  Any help would greatly appreciated.

Is there a better way I should be doing this other than creating a canvas in a class and trying to bind it to a canvas in the view?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Perhaps your Binding should be on the WaferMapCanvas property...looks like you used the class name WaferMap by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting your `DataContext` of your `mapCanvas` to `wtw.WaferMap.WaferMapCanvas`, which is an object of type `Canvas`, and `Canvas` does not have a property called `WaferMap`

You need to instead set the `DataContext` to `wtf.WaferMap` and bind to the `WaferMapCanvas` property which is of data type `Canvas`

```
mapCanvas.DataContext = wtw.WaferMap;
```

and

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding WaferMapCanvas}"/>
```

Comment: Rachel, thank you.  This is now working correctly.  Now if I want to move:  mapCanvas.DataContext = wtw.WaferMap to the constructor of my code behind instead of having it in a button click event handler, how would I do that?  When I set the data context of "mapCanvas" in the code-behind constructor, it does not work.  I did make sure to call "OnPropertyChanged" after drawing on the WaferMap.WaferMapCanvas, but the binding does not work doing it this way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @kformeck What property are you raising the `PropertyChange` notification for? It should be the `WaferMapCanvas`, so WPF knows it needs to re-evaluate that binding. Also, I couldn't help but notice that you are setting the `DataContext` in a lot of places. By default, XAML objects inherit their `DataContext` from the parent object, so you probably only need to set this once, such as `this.DataContext = wtw;`. For more information, see my blog post [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Rachel, you are incredible.  You solved my first problem with a single response.  I then had another question and you solved that in one response 8 minutes after you solved my first problem.  Thank you very much, I really appreciated all your help.

Comment: @kformeck Thanks, and I'm glad that worked out for you :) I spend a lot of time answering questions about WPF on SO, so I've gotten used to some of the more common mistakes